# Need help finding where the poles are located.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to evaluate
$$\int_{C} \frac{dz}{(z^{2}-1)^{2}+3},$$ where $C$ is the perimeter of the triangle with vertices $2, -2, 3i$ in the anti-clockwise direction.

The zeros of the denominator are $\pm \sqrt{1\pm i\sqrt{3}}$. I'm not sure which ones are inside of $C$, or how should I determine this.

Once I have the poles inside $C$, it's just a matter of finding $2\pi i \sum \mathrm{Res}(f; z_{i})$.

The residue at $z_{i}$ should be $\lim_{z\to z_{i}}\frac{1}{4z(z^{2}-1)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing it in exponential form, for example the one with all the pluses, you get $$\sqrt{2e^{i \arctan{\sqrt{3}}}}=\sqrt{2}e^{i \frac{\arctan{{\sqrt{3}}}}{2}}=\sqrt{2}e^{i \frac{\pi}{6}}$$
Now you can easily locate it; draw it and you'll most likely see if it's inside or not. Alternatively, use the inequalities that define the inside of the triangle